# Ruby on Rails Custom Method/Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I'm building out an app that does custom operations on defined nodes (the object). Here's my table:

```
<% @nodes.each do |node| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= node.name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Bootstrap', node_path(node),
              method: :bootstrap %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

"Bootstrap" is the custom code that I want to run. I'm defined a custom method within my Controller:

```
class NodesController < ApplicationController
  def bootstrap
     ......
  end
  ........
end
```

**How do I tie in my custom code to my Rails app so that when a user clicks on the link the code will be run against that object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `config/routes.rb`, you probably have:

```
resources :nodes
```

Change this to:

```
resources :nodes do
  get 'bootstrap', on: :member
end
```

Then, run `rake routes` to see that you now have a new route method, `bootstrap_node_path(node)`, and will link to `/nodes/:id/bootstrap`.

I recommend this over the other approach as it keeps your route details together, but that's just my personal opinion.  I usually resort to custom routes as a last resort.

Comment: I ended up adding it as a member resource